# Emberjs: controller and route not getting along

Tags: ember.js

The example will represent it best, I suppose. So, I have a defined route with a model property, which displays the appropriate image, based on id in url. This worked:

```
    App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {
            return App.Images.find(params.image_id);
        }
    });
```

However, I wanted to add an action and... when I set up the controller, the page did not have access to the model part. Controller:

```
    App.DetailsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        saveToServer: function(){
            //alert(JSON.stringify());
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
```

So at this time it's like this: either the model is set and stuff gets displayed and controller doesn't work OR controller works and model not.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you elaborate more your question ? I don't understand it well, and plural routes, are more common used to return a collection of objects, and in your DetailsRoute you're returning only one record, if you want that, then consider using a singular route, and change your controller's class, instead of 'DetailsController' to 'DetailController', and also consider defining you controller as an "Ember.ObjectController", that way, you will have a proxy to your model's properties

Comment: Here's my map:   `App.Router.map(function(){
   this.resource("main", {path: '/'});
   this.resource("details", {path: 'details/:image_id'});
  });` Could you give me an example of what you mean? Shouldn't Route be defined for details?

Comment: Thanks, changing it to `Ember.ObjectController` worked! could you please elaborate what's the difference? When to use one and when the other?

Comment: for routes, it is better if you define something like this:

this.resource('details')
this.resource('detail', path: 'detail/:detail_id')

that way, you could have a DetailsController, a DetailController, a DetailsRoute and a DetailRoute. DetailsRoute should return all(or a collection) of details, and DetailRoute should return only an instance:

App.DetailsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Detail.find();
  }
})

App.DetailRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Detail.find(params.detail_id)
  }
})

and the same for your controller